# Converting a double to intptr_t in C++

Tags: c++, casting

Assume the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   double a = 5.6;
   intptr_t b = (intptr_t) a;
   double c = (double) b;
   return 0;
}
```

`c` will be `5`. My question is, since `intptr_t` is also 64 bits on a 64 bit machine (same as double), how come the precision bits are not saved during casting?

Comment: Intptr_t is an integer, and floating point types convert to integers by truncation.

Comment: converting an `intptr_t` to double doesn't make sense. `double` doesn't have enough precision for the address for 64-bit architectures

Answer (score 2):

Although `intptr_t` is meant to represent a pointer to an int, its underling type is still an integer. Thus

```
intptr_t b = (intptr_t)a
```

Is still truncating the `double`, similar to if you'd just written:

```
int b = (int)a;
```

What you want to do is take the address of `a`:

```
intptr_t b = (intptr_t)&a
```

And then convert it back

```
double c = *(double*)b;
```